# Help identifying South Florida tree with large pink flowers that appear annually for a short time in the fall

Tags: identification, trees

[image: Tree by the Monza Publix]

[image: Beautiful tree by Monza Publix]

[image: Tree without its flowers]

Any ideas of what it could be?

*Edit: Added a picture without its flowers. The new image gives some reference for how tall it is and how much space its canopy covers.*

Comment: I don't think it is one, but if this tree interests you, you may also be interested in tulip trees, as they have large flowers similar to this, too.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, it's a Hong Kong Orchid Tree.

Comment: I added a picture of the tree without its flowers. Is this what a Hong Kong Orchid Tree looks like without its flowers?

Comment: Bauhinia blakeana, if it is Hong Kong orchid tree. Can't see leaf detail, which is important - should have twin lobed leaves if it is that tree.

Comment: If this is what the leaves look like on a Hong Kong orchid tree: http://toptropicals.com/pics/garden/m1/Podarki9/Bauhinia_Blakeana9MKh.jpg, then I don't think it's quite right. Though, I can't know for sure unless I get close to it again. I'll update when I pass by it again!

Answer (score 1):

That's not a Hong Kong orchid.  It's a silk floss tree,  [*Ceiba speciosa*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceiba_speciosa) (previously known as *Chlorisia speciosa*).

Comment: I agree. Bauhinia has very easily identifiable leaves and this is not a Bauhinia.